# $I$ is a free A-module if and only $I$ is principal

Tags: linear-algebra

***Problem:*** Let $A$ be an arbitrary integral domain and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$ considered as an $A$-submodule of $A^1 = A$. Show that $I$ is a free $A$-module if and only $I$ is principal.

The forward direction. Suppose that $I$ is free and admits a basis. I am thinking this amounts to showing that the basis consists of one non-zero element. How can I show this to be true?

According to the hint, let $u=-b$ and $v=a$ then $ua+vb=0$, and so $I$ cannot have more than $1$ basis vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Show  that for any two non-zero elements $a$ and $b$, there exists a non-trivial relation $ua+vb=0$.

Comment: On what grounds/theorems are you coming up with non-trivial $u,v$. It seems I need a hint for the hint.

Comment: Actually I understand and will post my answer.

Comment: This proves two non-zero elements are linearly dependent, hence a basis has at most one element.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ be a free ideal generated by $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$, $n>1$ you have $x_2x_1-x_1x_2=0$, this implies that $x_1=0$ or $x_2=0$ since $I$ is a free. Contradiction. You deduce that $n=1$.